# Divide an alphanumeric string into a map of numbers and strings

Tags: java, strings

Below is a bit of code which divides an alphanumeric string to a map of numbers and strings (assume numbers are single digits and non-repeating).

Example input:

```
String alphaNumericStr = "1abcdef2xyz9aaa6xxx";
```

Output:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = {1=abcdef, 2=xyz, 9=aaa, 6=xxx}
```

This is the code i wrote. While it gets the work done, this does not look like a clean solution to me. How can I make this better?

```
    String alphaNumericStr = "1abcdef2xyz9aaa6xxx";

    Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

    Character key = null;
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < alphaNumericStr.length(); i++) {
        Character c = alphaNumericStr.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                map.put(Character.getNumericValue(key), s.toString());
                s = new StringBuffer();

            }
            key = c;

        } else {
            s.append(c);
            if (i == alphaNumericStr.length() - 1) {
                map.put(Character.getNumericValue(key), s.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this regex [`(\d+)(\D+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zhliPG/1) which will match two groups, one is to match the number and the second to match the non digit part, beside If you are using [Java 9+ Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you can use simply :

```
String input = "1abcdef2xyz9aaa6xxx";
String regex = "(\\d+)(\\D+)";

Map<Integer, String> map = Pattern.compile(regex)
        .matcher(input)
        .results()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                m -> Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), m -> m.group(2)
        ));

System.out.println(map);
```

---

**Result**

```
{1=abcdef, 2=xyz, 9=aaa, 6=xxx}
```

---

If you are using Java 8 or lower, you can use :

```
String alphaNumericStr = "1abcdef2xyz9aaa6xxx";
String regex = "(\\d+)(\\D+)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(alphaNumericStr);

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    map.put(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)), matcher.group(2));
}
System.out.println(map);
```

---

But you will lose some information if the input contain the same number, in this case I would like to create a class which hold a number and a String and use a list in this case instead.

Comment: @ssubr check now the second solution!

Comment: You could simply make a `List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>` instead of creating a custom class for the list items.

Comment: This is also correct @Stingy

Answer (score 5):

Here are few changes from performance perspective. Actually they are not needed with your code as it invokes only once, but in case of frequent invocation, like an `View.onDraw()` method in Android, can really improve performance.

```
    String alphaNumericStr = "1abcdef2xyz9aaa6xxx";

    Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // diamond with a constructor of a generic class

    Character key = null;
    final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(); // StringBuilder is faster if multithreading not used

    // `size = alphaNumericStr.length()` actually not needed here but can
    // speed up performance in case of huge amount of invocations.
    // actually it's a default loop pattern in Android source code.
    for (int i = 0, size = alphaNumericStr.length(); i < size; i++) {
        Character c = alphaNumericStr.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                map.put(Character.getNumericValue(key), s.toString());
                // do not create new object in a loop. less work for GC
                s.delete(0, s.length());
            }
            key = c;
        } else {
            s.append(c);
        }
    }

    // move this out of the loop as it's needed only once.
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        map.put(Character.getNumericValue(key), s.toString());
    }

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential bug in your code.

If I had the input `12asdasd3xyz` I would have expected :

```
[12] : asdasd

[3]: xyz
```

But right now it would be :

```
[2] : asdasd

[3]: xyz
```

If you plan/need to fix this, you should keep the key as an `int` instead of a `Character` and in your if, find a way to "concat" your `ints` with something like this :

```
key = key * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(c)
```

Comment: The question defined the numbers in the string to be single digits, so this is not a bug.